# Stop counting when there is a collision

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a game when one Circle overlaps another circle, the score must add one.

But what happens it adds like 32 each time, obviously i know it adds each time it picks up a collision but how can i stop it and only count one for each collision.

please help here is my code.

```js
if (Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey1circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey2circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey3circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey4circle[i])) {
    escore++;
}
```

Comment: You need to show more relevant code.

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: Just keep a flag, when you first intersect set this flag, when you stop intersecting reset the flag.  Now when you intersect and the flag is not set, add score.

Comment: This is all that is necessary, everything works fine, i just need to stop counting when it picked up collision the first time.i dont know how.

Comment: Keith please do some coding on to add the flag please?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll have to (at the minimum) add a flag to keep track of the fact the intersection has happened/is occuring, and only run `escore++` as this changes from false to true. You'll also want to set the intersecting flag back to false when they are no longer intersecting if you want to track future collisions.

Comment: Will you please code it, so i can have a better understanding?

Comment: if (intersects && !flag) {
         flag = true;
         escore++
    }
    if (!intersects && flag) {
        flag = false
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach about how to use a flag combined with the collision detection

```js
boolean eycircle_flag ;
boolean collison ;

collison = Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey1circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey2circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey3circle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(playercircle, ey4circle[i]) ;

if(!eycircle_flag && collison)
{
  eycircle_flag = true ;
  escore++ ;
}
else if(eycircle_flag && !collision)
{
  eycircle_flag = false ;
}
```

Is up to you to decide if you need more flags or conditions to check and make this work for your needs

Comment: Not working ..means ? what did you expect, is there a compiler error ?

Comment: No, it the score still goes up to 81 when hitting one sprite

Comment: Keep in mind that the varialble ´eycircle_flag´ has to be kept outside the scope of the function where the collision is being checked, otherwise it will always be reset to false

Comment: it is defined directly under my Main class

Comment: I notice that you seem to have an array/list of 'ey1circle[i]' maybe you need more flags or debug the content of the flag to see what is failing

Comment: Nothing is failing it pics up collision, but i want it to stop immediately after the first collision have been picked up.then only on the second sprite it pics up again.

Comment: @Neillbar make sure that one the first collision is detected the flag is set to true and that is value is kept when the second collision is detected

Comment: Please give me an example

Comment: print/log the content of the variable or debug the code - for log see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html